# C# cannot cast T to T

Tags: c#, collections, casting, delegates

I have a generic collection `MyCollection<T>` that I've made, and everything works fine except this new function `Apply` that I'm adding:

```
class MyCollection<T> {
    T value;
    public MyCollection(T starter) { value = starter; }
    public MyCollection<S> Apply<T, S>(Func<T, S> function) {
        return new MyCollection<S>(function(value));  // error in function(value)
    }
}
```

This gives me an error I've never seen before:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'T' to 'T [C:\folder\code.cs (line number)]'
```

What are the two `T` types?  What's wrong with the conversion I'm attempting?

Comment: We issue compiler warnings for a reason. **Read them**. You have declared two *different* type paramaters *both called T*, and the compiler is telling you that fact. You should be getting compiler warning CS0693, which precisely diagnoses the problem.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the compiler code CS0693.  Googling it gave me the same feedback as in the answers below.  In the future, how can I find these codes without having to ask someone here?

Comment: I'm looking at the panel "Error List".  It shows (for each error/warning): an icon for error/warning, a number for its place in the list, a description, the code file causing it, the line number, the column number, and the name of the project.  It doesn't show any error code like CS0693.

Comment: Do you have warnings *turned off* by chance?

Comment: I doubt it, as I see warnings on a regular basis.

Comment: Do you have the warning level set to suppress level 3 warnings, by chance? Can you let me know the exact version number of the compiler / visual studio that you're using? If that warning is not being produced and you have warnings turned on then that's an extremely strange bug that I'd like to try to reproduce.

Comment: I haven't changed *any* settings, it's all out-of-the-box.  `Help > About` says this is Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 / Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel.

Comment: @EricLippert, any results?  I'd love to be able to see these compiler warnings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You problem is that the type parameter T in

```
class MyCollection<T>
```

is not the same type parameter as T in

```
Apply<T, S>
```

so your `function` takes another type than the type of `value`

if you change

```
Apply<T, S>
```

to

```
Apply<S>
```

your code will compile

Answer (score 5):

One T comes from `MyCollection<T>` and one from `Apply<T, S>`. `Apply<S>` should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to cast the generic type of the class to the generic type of the method. Remove the `T` from the signature of the `Apply` method.

```
class MyCollection<T> {
    T value;
    public MyCollection(T starter) { value = starter; }
    public MyCollection<S> Apply<S>(Func<T, S> function) {
        return new MyCollection<S>(function(value));
    } 
}
```